# What is the difference between apt-get and dpkg?

Tags: debian, package-management

I have several questions regarding `apt-get` vs. `dpkg`.

- Do they install to the same place?
- Is info from these tools 1 to 1 with each other?
- Is there any difference in the commands utility?

Comment: Click [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/309113/what-is-the-difference-between-dpkg-and-aptitude-apt-get/) to get more more detail about apt-get,dpkg and aptitude.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

`apt-get` makes use of `dpkg` to do the actual package installations. So in a sense they're "installing" to the same place.

I would always use `apt-get` to do any package management since this is the tool that understands how to source packages from remote repositories and provides capabilities for searching the meta data related to packages either locally or remotely.

That being said there are times where you'll have to make use of `dpkg` to perform queries against the system to find out information about the packages that are installed.

The major reason to use `apt` tools though is for the dependency management. The `apt` tools understand that in order to install a given package, other packages may need to be installed too, and `apt` can download these and install them, whereas `dpkg` does not.

Comment: Thank you that is exactly what I needed. Possibly you can offer advice on http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/104594/track-down-executables-installer also

Comment: @user54189 - what sort of advice regarding the Q? The commands `dpkg -L` and `dpkg -S` are 2 scenarios where you need to resort to dpkg to get this type of meta information. The `apt` tools do not have it in an easy to access fashion.

Comment: Most queries that you can perform with `dpkg-query` can also be performed by `aptitude` and sometimes by `apt-cache`.

Comment: OK. So does it mean that dpkg will always give a more comprehensive list of all the packages installed on the system (including dependencies etc.) than apt-get ? And is it safe to assume that dpkg can be used to list ALL the software (user/system/etc. applications) installed on a system ?

Comment: @qre0ct - that's a new question ask it on the main site and reference this question.

Comment: @slm cool. Done [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/343152/dpkg-or-apt-get-whcih-of-the-two-gives-a-more-complete-result) Requesting help