# track down executables installer

Tags: debian, package-management, apt

I have a freshly installed debian  system

It has vim installed using `apt-get install vim` 
 
 Now I have the command xxd installed on the system. I know that this had to have come from the vim installation but I can not find the commands installer.

How can I track down what it was that has installed this command.

Comment: What do you mean by “executables installer”? Debian (like most Linux distributions) has a single installer: APT (which has multiple frontends, but it's all the same database underneath). If you mean which package `xxd` comes from, see Zelda's answer (but the answer is unsurprisingly xxd).

Answer (score 3):

If you mean with `what it was` from which package `xxd` did come, you can use:

```
dpkg -S $(which xxd)
```

(on my system it is part of `vim-common`)

To see everything that is installed with `vim-common` you can do:

```
dpkg -L vim-common
```