# dpkg or apt-get which of the two gives a more complete result?

Tags: ubuntu, apt, package-management, dpkg

I want to figure out EACH and EVERY package/software installed on an Ubuntu (14.04/16.04) system.

From my understanding and several discussions on SE and elsewhere, like [unix_stack_exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/104592/what-is-the-difference-between-apt-get-and-dpkg/104593) [ask_ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/309113/what-is-the-difference-between-dpkg-and-aptitude-apt-get/), it looks like whatever packages/software is installed on the system, dpkg will ultimately be used (be it for the package itself or it's dependencies).

1. So does it mean that dpkg will always give a more comprehensive list
   of all the packages installed on the system (including dependencies
   etc.) than apt-get ?
2. And is it safe to assume that dpkg can be used to list ALL the
   software (user/system/etc. applications) installed on a system ?

Answer (score 7):

`dpkg -l` will always give the correct list of installed (or removed but still configured) packages. It actually uses `dpkg-query` to do its job, and that references the contents of `/var/lib/dpkg/status` which is *the* reference for installed packages.

`apt` uses the same information, but until recently didn't provide an easy way to list packages; `apt list` now does that, and you'll get the same results as given by `dpkg -l` (in a different format).

`dpkg` can be used to list *all packages*. If all the software on a system is installed using packages, then it will list all the software; but if any software has been installed manually, without a package, then it won't know about it.

Comment: So in case of manually installed things, say python modules installed via pip etc. is there a generic linux way of figuring out all of these as well, I mean without actually using pip or python utilities itself. I want it to be generic enough that I can simply use it to figure out all possible modules/plugins etc. of any software, eg. vim, python etc.?

Comment: There's no generic way as far as I know. On Debian derivatives, tools such as `cruft` (in the `cruft` package) can help you list files on your system which don't come from packages, but figuring out where they come from and what they correspond to is a manual process.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `apt` with options (`man apt-cache` , `man apt` ..) to get the needed information

> [**dpkg or apt?**](https://debian-handbook.info/browse/stable/sect.manipulating-packages-with-dpkg.html)
>
> `dpkg` should be seen as a system tool (backend), and `apt` as a tool closer to the user, which overcomes the limitations of the former. These tools work together, each one with its particularities, suited to specific tasks.

e,g 1: you can list the installed package on your system through `dpkg` or `apt`:

```
apt list --installed
dpkg -l
```

e,g 2 :To find out the dependencies you can use `apt-rdepends` , or `apt-cache showpkg` ...

```
apt-rdepends <package_name>
apt-cache showpkg <package_name>
```